# Simple ngBind doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I have this example where you enter a value in the input field which should be shown elsewhere, but the ngBind doesn't work in this case. Does anyone know why?

Here's my html:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="headerInput">Header</label> 
      <div class="col-sm-10"><input ng-model="content.header" type="text" class="form-control" id="headerInput" >
        <p ng-bind="content.header"></p>
      </div>
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textInput">Text</label> 
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input ng-model="content.text" type="text" class="form-control" id="textInput" >
        <p ng-bind="content.text"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and here is my controller :

```
 var a = angular.module('ACtrl',[]);
 a.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.content = {};
 }]);
```

Comment: The exact code in the question [works fine here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TVq6StmjY8oROaEKFwPg?p=preview). Issue could be else where please show us a demonstration of the issue.

Comment: Have you added `ng-app="ACtrl"` to the html tag, and `ng-controller="ExampleController"` to an element higher up the DOM than what you've shown here?